# Remove part of first row in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to figure out how to remove 'none' in the first
row of a list.

```
y = ['none,none,none,none,none,none,OBJECTID,FULL_ADDRESS', '8724,CANARY',
     '8759,CARDINAL', '9774,W WABASH', '17745,WESTCHESTER']
```

I've tried:

```
if 'none' in y[0]:
    y.remove('none')
print y
```

Comment: Could do `if 'none' in y: del y[0]` since you're want to remove the first element if it contains none... `list.remove` looks for an element equalling its argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to remove none and the comma after --

```
if 'none,' in y[0]:
    y[0] = y[0].replace('none,','')
print y
```

You don't even need the "if statement" if you don't want.

```
>>> y = ['none,none,none,none,none,none,OBJECTID,FULL_ADDRESS', '8724,CANARY',
     '8759,CARDINAL', '9774,W WABASH', '17745,WESTCHESTER']
>>> y[0] = y[0].replace('none,','')
>>> y
['OBJECTID,FULL_ADDRESS', '8724,CANARY', '8759,CARDINAL', '9774,W WABASH', '17745,WESTCHESTER']
>>> y[0] = y[0].replace('none,','')
>>> y
['OBJECTID,FULL_ADDRESS', '8724,CANARY', '8759,CARDINAL', '9774,W WABASH', '17745,WESTCHESTER']
>>>
```

Comment: appreciate that Chris

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ','.join([x for x in y[0].split(',') if x != 'none'])
'OBJECTID,FULL_ADDRESS'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `y.remove('none')` because `'none'` isn't a member of `y`, it's a substring of a member of `y`.

The clean way to handle this is to "normalize" your data structures. If you want to treat `y[0]` as a list of multiple values, break it into a list of multiple values instead of keeping it as a string. For example:

```
>>> y = [x.split(',') for x in y]
>>> y
[['none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'OBJECTID', 'FULL_ADDRESS'],
 ['8724', 'CANARY'],
 ['8759', 'CARDINAL'],
 ['9774', 'W WABASH'],
 ['17745', 'WESTCHESTER']]
```

And now it's easy to remove the `'none'` elements, because there *are* `'none'` elements to remove:

```
>>> y = [[value for value in row if value != 'none'] for row in y]
```

Or, if you want to do it destructively:

```
>>> for row in y:
...     while 'none' in row:
...         row.remove('none')
```

---

In fact, it looks like what you've done is read a CSV file in as a bunch of lines instead of as a CSV. If so, the real solution is to change that to use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read it in the first place.